# How to get more details of a potential GPU hardware failure on a Windows 10 system?

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming

I started getting hardware failures out of nowhere yesterday and haven’t been able to fix them. I even went so far as to re-install Windows 10 and all the drivers.

The only place I’ve been able to find info on what’s happening is in the Reliability report and that shows a `LiveKernelEvent` with `Code: 141`. I can’t find anything helpful about what that means nor can I find any logs.

I am able to use browsers and Flash just fine, but my system locks up a few minutes after launching a game and I need to hard shutdown to get things back up again. When it happens my monitor shows blue as if there were no input (not BSOD), and my voice chat works for a few more seconds before things ultimately locks up and I have to mercy kill it.

Where or how can I find more information about what’s causing this error? It seems like it’s GPU related.

Comment: Had a similar issue before and helped other people on this topic. In all instances, the pc would only crash or lock up while gaming. The resolution was moving the GPU to a different PCIe slot. Give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: I'll try that out tonight when I get home from work!